# Swift - Index out of range in UITableVewController

Tags: swift, swift2

I have an array of friends, arrays of their related information. I'm render cells in a table view, and this works great. I can cause the app to crash though if I scroll up/down with a lot of clicking all over the screen... and I can't for the life of me understand why!

This is the error: **fatal error: Index out of range**

There doesn't seem to be rhyme or reason as to why this happens, and it's really confusing. Insight would be appreciated.

This is the failing class:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PictureCell
    let pos = self.positiveVoteArray.reduce(0,combine: {$0 + $1})
    let neg = self.negativeVoteArray.reduce(0,combine: {$0 + $1})
    let progress = (pos + neg)/pos

//Fails below this line, first reference to indexPath.row //
    cell.usernameBtn.setTitle(usernameArray[indexPath.row], forState: .Normal)
    cell.uuidLbl.text = uuidArray[indexPath.row]

    avaArray[indexPath.row].getDataInBackgroundWithBlock { (data:NSData?, error:NSError?) in
        if error == nil {
            cell.avaImg.image = UIImage(data: data!)
        }
    }

    if votedFriendsArray.contains((PFUser.currentUser()?.username!)!) {
        cell.scoreBar.hidden = false;
        cell.dislikeBtn.hidden = true;
        cell.likeBtn.hidden = true;
        cell.scoreBar.setProgress(progress, animated: true)

    } else {
        cell.scoreBar.hidden = true;
        cell.dislikeBtn.hidden = false;
        cell.likeBtn.hidden = false;
    }

    picArray[indexPath.row].getDataInBackgroundWithBlock { (data:NSData?, error:NSError?) in
        if error == nil {
            cell.picImg.image = UIImage(data: data!)
        }
    }

    // assign index
    cell.usernameBtn.layer.setValue(indexPath, forKey: "index")

    return cell
}
```

Comment: On which line do you get the error?

Comment: @SamM the error is below the comment, line 8

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely setting the wrong number of rows in the `tableView(UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection: Int)`. It needs to be set to `usernameArray.count` and you need to make sure it stays current (if you are removing items). And looking at the next line, count of `uuidArray` must be the same as `usernameArray`.

Comment: so I'm using usernameArray.count.. but maybe I should use uuidArray.count. What i'm doing is when I click on a cell I navigate to a new view and push uuidArray[indexPath.row], and when I nav back I pop that. This works great usually, but if I tap/scroll a bunch I get the error..

Why would this be **sometimes** causing an error?

Comment: Check the count of `uuidArray`- it needs to have at least as many items as `usernameArray`.